# Write the algebra closure of $F_p$ as union of finite fields

Tags: nt.number-theory, finite-fields, fields

This question follows [Field theory by Steven Roman](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007%2F0-387-27678-5), Chapter 9, Exercise 20.

Denote the algebraic closure of the finite field $F_q$ by $\Gamma(q)$, and let $a_n$ be any strictly increasing infinite sequence of positive integers. The exercise wants us to prove that $\Gamma(q)=\bigcup_{n=0}^{\infty}GF(q^{a_n})$.

However, if $a_n$ is an arbitrary sequence, we are even unable to prove $\bigcup_{n=0}^{\infty}GF(q^{a_n})$ is a field. I wonder whether the exercise has omitted some condition since the equality doesn't hold under the stated conditions.

In fact, I believe that to demand that $a_n$ is any sequence of positive integers such that any positive integer $k$ divides some $a_n$ is both sufficient and necessary, though I'm not sure.

Hope for answers!

Comment: It's not a field, for instance is $a_n$ is the $n$-th prime. If $a_n=2^n$ it's a field, but it's not algebraically closed...

Comment: Right you are. Perhaps the easiest way to remedy the author’s failing is to replace “any strictly increasing infinite sequence” with “the sequence $a_n=n!$”.

Comment: Certainly your condition is sufficient.  For necessity, note that a primitive element of $\mathrm{GF}(q^b)$ has order $q^b - 1$, hence lies in $\mathrm{GF}(q^a)$, whose multiplicative group has order $q^a - 1$, if and only if $q^b - 1 \mid q^a - 1$, which, since $\gcd(q^b - 1, q^a - 1) = q^{\gcd(a, b)} - 1$, is true if and only if $b \mid a$.

Comment: The same question on Mathematics: [Write the algebra closure of $F_p$ as union of finite fields](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3030335). [This answer](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/2637/cross-posts-to-math-se#2638) has some reasonable advice about cross-posting. Another things to keep in mind is that this site has different tags. For example, the tag (abstract-algebra) [is deprecated](https://mathoverflow.net/tags/abstract-algebra/info) and it is recommended to use [at least one top-level tag](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/1457/why-are-mo-tags-formatted-as-they-are).

Comment: @MartinSleziak Thanks for your advice. As a new contributor, I'll learn from this.

Comment: By the way, the "I believe that" addendum was added by the OP after it was suggested as a comment (by @reuns) on the MathSE site. This is not very fair conduct.

Answer (score 2):

What you say sounds fine. The absolute Galois group of $F_q$ is $\widehat{\mathbb{Z}}$ and if you take some infinite quotient of this like $\mathbb{Z}_2$ (corresponding to a closed subgroup) then that corresponds to an infinite extension of $F_q$ with Galois group $\mathbb{Z}_2$, which you can write as the union of $GF(q^2)$, $GF(q^4)$, $GF(q^8)$, $GF(q^{16})$ and so on. If now you also throw in $GF(q^3)$ then you have something which is not a field. In general, as subfields of $\Gamma(q)$, $GF(q^a)$ is a subfield of $GF(q^b)$ if and only if $a$ divides $b$, so if you want the union to be all of $\Gamma(q)$ then you'd better have $GF(q^k)$ for all $k$ so you'd better have a multiple of $k$ in your sequence of $a_i$.

Comment: ... it's about research level mathematics.